# show() jquery function slide down all of my content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 navbars on my website, when I `show()` my second navbar all of my content on website is going down width the height of my navbar, how to stop this?

I want just to show navbar on my content (`z-index`) and don't slide down content after navbar.

What should I do? `bottom:-100px;` doesn't work.

Regards.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is troubling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that navbar is not 
    position:absolute
try changing the position in the css to be absolute and then it should work

Comment: When I add `position:absolute;` it doesn't show me my navbar because above it I have primary navbar.

Comment: yea now that you changed to `position:absolute` the div is not positioned after its preceding item anymore but rather it is positioned relative to the next parent element which has `position:relative` (which could be a container or body).

So you now need to reposition it using the attribute top e.g.
    `top:100px:`

Comment: also check z-index